# azure media service stuck

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have created a new media service on microsoft azure.
Then I have downloaded the code sample from msdn.
I tried to use the code in order to upload a file but the visual studio is stuck
on the uploading file line 
(assetFile.Upload(singleFilePath);)

There is no exception.
The visual studio is just stuck.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: You can use fiddler to see what is going on. Maybe the file is being transferred

Comment: It seems like the upload command opened an http tunnel. It transfers something like 90% of the file and than just opened another tunnel and starts from zero again.